# Where can I find a list of calling numbers used by Google Calendar SMS service

Tags: google-calendar, sms

I frequently use SMS notifications in Google Calendar, but I seem to receive the SMS message from a different sending number each time. So my SMS list is full of different "random" numbers.

I'd like to add a "Google Calendar" contact, adding all its phone numbers in order to get all the SMS messages in the same thread, under a unique name.

Is there a list of all the phone numbers used by Google Agenda to send the SMS?

Comment: For what it's worth, [you're not the only person having trouble with this](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/804AFAXlcZI). It seems to be a recent phenomenon.

Comment: OK, I'm not alone, cool :). But in my case (in France), this has always been like this, as far as I remember... This is not a new issue.